# Theming Sencha project using ScoutApp

Tags: css, extjs, sass, compass-sass, scout-sass

I am trying for the first time to theming my sencha project by using Scout/Compass GUI because i am not familiar with ruby and the command line.
I have installed Scout then i have created a new scss file form copynig the defalut one and renaming it .

After that,i have modified index.html to include the new css file.
Still one task to achieve:Compiling my theme
Please look at the picture below:
[image]

After running i obtain the following log:
[image]

I am not recognising the error.
Please help me.Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It cannot work with Sencha Touch or Ext JS. Both of these project require extra framework SASS files, which is including in the `config.rb` file for each project. From what I can see, Scout creates its own `config.rb` file and then uses that to compile your project. Because you cannot include the framework SASS files in that generated file, you cannot use Scout.

Answer (score 0):

**input Folder** is **C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch-2.0.0-gpl\resources\sass**